# Split the input file-format into a multiple lines list, interpolating number ranges "n-m"

Tags: python, interpolation, file-format

I would need help to separate the csv into a list.
Here is the input file and out put file that I need.

I have a CSV file which look like this (line by line):

```
1-6
97
153,315,341,535
15,~1510,~1533,~1534,~1535,~1590
```

I need my output to be:

```
Col 1    Col 2
1        ~1510        
2        ~1533
3        ~1534
4        ~1535
5        ~1590
6
97
153
315
341
535
15
```

Meaning when I detect "-" sign example 1-6 will be (1 until 6)
and separate the number with and without "~" into 2 different column

However results i get with my code is as below:

```
Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4    Col5    Col6
6-Jan
97
153     315      341    535
15      ~1510    ~1533  ~1534   ~1535   ~1590
```

my code:

```
import csv

with open('testing.csv') as f, open("testing1.csv", "w") as outfile:
  writer = csv.writer(outfile)
  f.readline() # these are headings should remove them
  csv_reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=",")
  for line_list in csv_reader:
    skills_list = [line_list[0].split(',')]
    for skill in skills_list:
        writer.writerow(skill)
```

Please help. Thanks A lot.

Comment: The input is not a valid CSV file.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it. read all the data first and construct your columns. Then iterate over the columns and build your csv.

Here is code for building the columns.

```
import csv
fin = open('testing.csv', 'r')
column_1 = []
column_2 = []
for line in fin:
    items = line.split(',')
    for item in items:
        if '-' in item:
            num_range = item.split('-')
            column_1 += range(int(num_range[0])+1, int(num_range[1])+1)
        elif '~' in item:
            column_2.append(item.strip())
        else:
            column_1.append(item.strip())

fin.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot write output until you have read the required input. So the first output line can be written when you have obtained the input `~1510`.

The simplest solution is to read the entire input file into memory, then write. I would maintain two lists, then push to the first if no tilde, otherwise to the other one. For output, then, simply loop over these lists, supplying empty values if one of them runs out.

If you need to optimize memory usage (e.g. if there is more input than you can fit into memory), maybe write each line as soon as you can and free up its memory; but this is more challenging to get right.

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools as it

results = {
    'col1': [],
    'col2': [],
}

with open('data.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.rstrip()
        entries = line.split(",")

        for entry in entries:
            if entry.startswith('~'):
                column = 'col2'
                entry = entry[1:]
            else:
                column = 'col1'

            if '-' in entry:
                start, end = entry.split('-')
                results[column].extend(
                    list(range(int(start), int(end)+1))
                )
            else:
                results[column].append(entry)

print("{} \t {}".format('Col 1', 'Col 2'))

column_iter = it.zip_longest(
    results['col1'], 
    ["~{}".format(num) for num in results['col2']], 
    fillvalue=''
)

for col1_num, col2_num in column_iter:
    print(
        "{} \t {}".format(col1_num, col2_num)
    )


--output:--
Col 1    Col 2
1        ~1510
2        ~1533
3        ~1534
4        ~1535
5        ~1590
6    
97   
153      
315      
341      
535      
15
```

And with this data.txt:

```
1-6
~7-10,97
153,315,341,535
15,~1510,~1533,~1534,~1535,~1590
```

output:

```
Col 1    Col 2
1        ~7
2        ~8
3        ~9
4        ~10
5        ~1510
6        ~1533
97       ~1534
153      ~1535
315      ~1590
341      
535      
15
```